# How to get the tags for the installed software in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, software-center, scripts

I can retrieve the softwares using the dpkg command but is there a command to get the associated category for the software .
For example  if I have Firefox installed can I somehow retrieve a tag for it that says browser or may be a more abstract term say internet tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dpkg-query` and format the output to get the binary name and its Debian [section](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-subsections):

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package} (${Section})\n' firefox
```

For firefox it will simply return `firefox (web)` (the same section used when querying [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=trusty&section=all))

Of course you can also use the same command without a package name:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package} (${Section})\n'
```

See the `dpkg-query` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) for further details.

---

To get the categories as shown in the Software Center you need to parse files in /usr/share/applications like this:

```
$ grep Categories /usr/share/applications/* | grep firefox
/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop:Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
```

To get only the most specific applicable category, you could try this:

```
$ grep Categories /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop | awk -F';' '{print $(NF-1)}'
WebBrowser
```

Comment: Thanks for spending some of your valuable time with Ask Ubuntu. :)

Comment: I tried the command it returns me web for the firefox but gnome for rhythmbox but when i see software center it lists it under sound and video category .So any other query to produce the same outcome ?

Comment: Moreover when i run software-center in debug mode it seems like it queries the software internal tools and gets the categories the way i want them for eg. Ruby python are coming under developer tools and more. Can anything be done about it ?

Comment: I've updated my answer using the freedesktop Categories

Comment: Thanks alot. Would not have got a better answer than yours.Very much appreciated. @SylvainPineau